# Using CSS to make button appear on Select Drop Down menu in Chrome / Webkit Browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, button, drop-down-menu, webkit

So I have a simple drop down menu in HTML like this:

```
<select name="menu" class="menu">
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
</select>
```

And I am styling it with this CSS:

```
.menu {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    outline: none;
    border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
    border-top-style: none !important;
    border-right-style: none !important;
    border-bottom-style: solid !important;
    border-left-style: none !important;
    border-bottom-color: #999 !important;
    width:200px;
    -webkit-border:0;
    -webkit-appearance: button;
}
```

This renders as I want it to in Firefox and Internet Explorer - the drop down menu has a 1px border along the bottom only, and has the drop down menu button (grey button with small down arrow) to the right hand side.

But in Chrome, or other WebKit browsers (like Safari), the button does not appear.

I have been toying around with the `-webkit-appearance` rule, playing around with the properties found here http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-appearance but with little success.

- Without this rule the drop down menu renders with a box around it and
  the button on the right hand side.
- With this rule the drop down menu renders with just the 1px border
  along the bottom, but no button on the right hand side.

My question is, how do I get this drop down menu to render in Chrome as it does in Firefox, with the button on the right and just a single 1px border along the bottom?

Here is a jsFiddle so you can see for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/tkFpe/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use border all white colored but bottom with other color for a proper dropdown menu. check this fiddle [jsfiddle.net/LGwEd/3](http://jsfiddle.net/LGwEd/3).

```
.menu { 
    font-size: 10px; 
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif; 
    padding-top: 2px; 
    position: relative; 
    bottom: 2px; 
    outline: none; 
    width:200px; 
    border:0; 
    appearance: menulist-button; 
}
```

Comment: I am using this, in which border is zero. .menu {
    font-size: 10px;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    padding-top: 2px;
    position: relative;
    bottom: 2px;
    outline: none;
    width:200px;
    border:0;
    appearance: menulist-button;
} check on this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LGwEd/1/

Comment: ok, that makes the button appear to the right, but not the single 1px border along the bottom. is there any way to get both appearing in Chrome?

Comment: Try this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yfLuG you will notice that there is no border around everything, just the bottom, however the contour in chrome and safari make it look as if it has a border all around

Comment: is there anyway of getting rid of this contour?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think it is the way that the -webkit engine renders the buttons (all nice and rounded) versus the -moz engine which is more "correct" or "plain". I've had this issue in the past and given up using input fields of a certain nature. I now generally wrap the input field in a div and use the background as a graphic.

Comment: one thing to note, the appearance: attribute is not supported in IE or Opera, that is why i recommended to remove it.

Comment: Yeah same as fizzy, not sure if contour can be removed or not. But You can hack(or fack) it with white borders in other sides. check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LGwEd/3/.

Comment: @crazyrohila many thanks. update your answer with this new fiddle and i will mark your answer as correct! :)

Comment: thanks jimmery! I updated the answer. This is my first day on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

remove the -webkit part, and use just border: 0 and appearance: button;

this made it work for me using: Chrome 25.0  and Safari: 6.0.2